# Pyspark Format Dates

Tags: date, pyspark, parquet

I have imported a CSV file by parsing it through pandas, then I converted the csv file to parquet format.

The data read Time as *bigint* and date as *String*

I can change the date using the to_date function i.e. `df.withColumn('ObservationDate', to_date('ObservationDate'))`.

However, I am struggling to change the Time column to HH format, and I also struggling to add the hours to the Date column. I have looked at the spark documents, but I am not able to find what I am looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative-

**`lpad`** to convert in hour to `**HH`** format & **`unix_timestamp` addition by setting `UTC` as spark session timezone

```scala
 df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---------------+-------------------+
      * |ObservationTime|ObservationDate    |
      * +---------------+-------------------+
      * |1              |2016-02-01T00:00:00|
      * |12             |2016-02-01T00:00:00|
      * +---------------+-------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- ObservationTime: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- ObservationDate: string (nullable = true)
      */

    spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
    df.withColumn("ObservationTime", lpad($"ObservationTime", 2, "0"))
      .withColumn("new_ObservationDate",
        (unix_timestamp($"ObservationDate".cast("timestamp")).cast("long") + unix_timestamp($"ObservationTime", "HH").cast("long"))
          .cast("timestamp")
      )
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---------------+-------------------+-------------------+
      * |ObservationTime|ObservationDate    |new_ObservationDate|
      * +---------------+-------------------+-------------------+
      * |01             |2016-02-01T00:00:00|2016-02-01 01:00:00|
      * |12             |2016-02-01T00:00:00|2016-02-01 12:00:00|
      * +---------------+-------------------+-------------------+
      */
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert Time column to HH format use **`format_string()`** function then to add Time to date column use **`to_timestamp()`** function.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+---------------+-------------------+
#|ObservationTime|    ObservationDate|
#+---------------+-------------------+
#|              1|2016-02-01T00:00:00|
#|             12|2016-02-01T00:00:00|
#+---------------+-------------------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("HH",format_string("%02d",col("ObservationTime"))).\
withColumn("new_date",to_timestamp(concat(to_date(col("ObservationDate")),lit(' '),format_string("%02d",col("ObservationTime"))),"yyyy-MM-dd HH")).\
show()
#+---------------+-------------------+---+-------------------+
#|ObservationTime|    ObservationDate| HH|           new_date|
#+---------------+-------------------+---+-------------------+
#|              1|2016-02-01T00:00:00| 01|2016-02-01 01:00:00|
#|             12|2016-02-01T00:00:00| 12|2016-02-01 12:00:00|
#+---------------+-------------------+---+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.show(10, False)

df.withColumn('ObservationTime', f.lpad('ObservationTime', 2, '0')) \
  .withColumn('ObservationDate', f.to_timestamp('ObservationDate')) \
  .withColumn('ObservationTimestamp', f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp('ObservationDate') + f.unix_timestamp('ObservationTime', 'H'))) \
  .show(10, False)

+---------------+-------------------+
|ObservationTime|ObservationDate    |
+---------------+-------------------+
|1              |2016-02-01T00:00:00|
|14             |2016-02-01T00:00:00|
+---------------+-------------------+

+---------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|ObservationTime|ObservationDate    |ObservationTimestamp|
+---------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|01             |2016-02-01 00:00:00|2016-02-01 01:00:00 |
|14             |2016-02-01 00:00:00|2016-02-01 14:00:00 |
+---------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

I have used the `unix_timestamp` function for the ObservationTime with `'H'` but it would be `'HH'` in the Spark 2.x.